# Aggregating distinct values from a child table as an attribute on a parent table in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a one-to-many relationship set up like this in sqlalchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey

Base = declarative_base()

class Status(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'status'

    name = Column(String(32), primary_key=True, unique=True)

class Chunk(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'chunk'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    taskId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('task.id'))
    status = Column(String(32), ForeignKey('status.name'), default='unassigned')

class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'task'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

`Tasks` contain a list of `Chunks`.  Each chunk has its own `status`.

I'd like to add a `column_property` or `hybrid_property` to `Task` that would return the distinct set of statuses for that Task's chunks.

I've tried to use `column_property` like this:

```
Task.statuses = column_property(
    select([func.distinct(Chunk.status)]).\
    where(Chunk.taskId == Task.id).\
    correlate(Task.__table__)
)
```

But this gives errors about the select returning more than one value:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `group_concat`.  The results come back as a comma-separated string, but that's ok.

```
Task.statuses = column_property(
    select([func.group_concat(distinct(Chunk.status))]).\
    where(Chunk.taskId == Task.id).\
    correlate(Task.__table__)
)
```